# Implicit multiplication order of operation

Tags: arithmetic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is 48÷2(9+3)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33215/what-is-48293)

$\begin{equation}
48 \div 2(9+3) = ?
\end{equation}$

Is the answer to that 2 or 288?

What is the order of operations for implicit multiplication?