# Confusing with basic arithmetics, BODMAS

Tags: arithmetic

What is the result of $6\div 2(1+2)$?

I simplified the bracket with the $2$ outside first and my final answer was $1$.

But I'm kind of getting confused because alpha mathematica evaluates this same expression for $9$. I'm I right? I have no other ways of justifying this.

Comment: [BODMAS](https://www.cuemath.com/numbers/bodmas-rule/): Brackets, O - Order of powers or roots, (in some cases, 'of'), D - Division, M - Multiplication A - Addition, and S - Subtraction. And work from left to right.

Comment: The expression is intentionally ambiguous. A good explanation can be found here, for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q0przEtP19s.

Comment: Your brackets step is correct, and there is no power. So next is division and multiplication. And the expression has both a division and a multiplication. So do them from left to right in the expression.

Comment: also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16502/do-values-attached-to-integers-have-implicit-parentheses

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2660193/what-the-solve-for-this-sentence and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35809/operator-precedence and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/793402/what-is-6221-and-why and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198747/proof-of-equality and probably more.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I see that it is an ambiguous expression