# What is the "status" of the rule that multiplication precedes addition.

Tags: real-analysis, notation, arithmetic

What is the source, or "status", of the rule that multiplication is performed before addition?

Is it a definitive property of $\mathbb R$, a property that can be derived directly from the definition of $\mathbb R$, or simply a (universal but arbitrary) notational convention?

---

For example, in Spivak's *Calculus* (4E, p. 7) the distributive law ("P9") is stated as
$$a \cdot (b+c) = a\cdot b + a\cdot c \text{ ,}$$
which is simply understood, without further justification, to mean
$$a \cdot (b+c) = (a\cdot b) + (a\cdot c)\text{ .}$$
Should this interpretation have been derivable from the earlier-stated properties of $\mathbb R$, or is it simply being assumed as shared knowledge?

Comment: Note that this is *not* a [repeat of the](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/33215/12400) about the pernicious [memes](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/48293) regarding how to evaluate simple arithmetic problems, or about the "[order of operation](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/36270/12400)" rules used to to dismiss them; but rather about the *origin* and mathematical "status" of *one* of those rules.

Comment: It is merely a notational convention that allows one to omit parentheses in order to obtain more concise notation.

Comment: @BillDubuque: That looks like an answer to me.

Comment: Do check this great thread: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/119274/why-do-we-need-use-operator-precedence-for-arithmetic-operators

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Such operator precedence rules are merely *syntactic* conventions that are adopted for convenience. They improve the conciseness of commonly denoted expressions by allowing one to omit some parentheses, while preserving *unique* readability (parsing) of expressions. For example, such conventions enable the standard concise notation for ubiquitous polynomial expressions. For another example see my [answer here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/24253/242) In other words, such syntactic conventions are simply optimizations of the language used to denote certain expressions. As conventions, they have little if any *semantic* significance.

[Comment migrated to an answer per request]

Comment: Then why not let the addition precede the multiplication? Or forget about the precedence and just parse a long expression from left to right as it is written? Such approaches can still achieve the same unambiguity and conciseness as long as everyone agrees so.

Answer (score 6):

Note that under a different convention precedence can be different. For example, under  Łukasiewicz notation ([Polish Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation#Order_of_operations) or [R]PN) the order of operations is entirely different, in fact it is trivial.

I think that the questioner also wanted to know the source of such conventions. [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180111045655/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52582.html) presents a quite thorough history of operator precedence and operation grouping. On point:

> The convention that multiplication precedes addition and subtraction
> was in use in the earliest books employing symbolic algebra in the
> 16th century.

Although precedence seems to have existed in its current form for as long as the math has been used, there are some interesting exceptions.  For example:

> an early notation in which a multiplication would be replaced by a comma to indicate aggregation:
>
> ```
>   n, n - 1
> ```
>
> would mean
> $n(n - 1)$
>
> whereas
>
> ```
>  n n - 1
> ```
>
> meant
> $n^2 - 1$

However - this is just the history, as @BillDubuque correctly states in his answer, these are all merely a notational convention.

Answer (score 2):

That multiplication precedes addition is a notational convention, not a mathematical proposition.

Comment: Why repeat my comment that was posted a half-hour earlier, without adding anything new?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Just quote some great answer from [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/119275/1005):

> ...there is no need for operator precedence. There are a number of other
> conventions that have been used in various contexts. A few programming
> languages have implemented the left-to-right convention you mention in
> the question, and a larger number have avoided the problem entirely by
> using Polish notation or its reverse.
>
> The purpose of operator precedence conventions is to reduce the number
> of parentheses that are required to unambiguously communicate ideas
> that occur in practical mathematical usage. The most important
> rules—that multiplication has a higher precedence than addition, and
> exponentiation has a higher precedence than multiplication—exist
> primarily for the convenience of writing polynomials. Without these
> rules, polynomial expressions would require far more parentheses.
> Polynomials are so central to mathematical practice that they bleed
> into the notation, in operator precedence and elsewhere.

(I will delete this answer if mere quotation doesn't qualify an answer.)

Comment: Please don't duplicate prior  answers. This has already been said (a bit more concisely) in my answer.