# Why got multiplication and division higher priority than addition and subtraction?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the “status” of the rule that multiplication precedes addition.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97452/what-is-the-status-of-the-rule-that-multiplication-precedes-addition)

I know it's some kind of axiom, that "1 + 2 * 3" is the same as "1 + (2 * 3)", but who defined it? Why is it so widely used? Why couldn't have addition priority?