# Priority of parentheses and brackets in basic arithmetic.

Tags: arithmetic, wolfram-alpha

Wolfram alpha is giving inconsistent results to this problem:

When I enter:

[16÷2( 8-3(4-2) )+1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=16%C3%B72%28%208-3%284-2%29%20%29%2b1)
the result is 17.

When I enter:

[16÷2[ 8-3(4-2) ]+1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=16%C3%B72%5B%208-3%284-2%29%20%5D%2b1) the result is 5.

and

[16÷2*[ 8-3(4-2) ]+1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=16%C3%B72*%5B%208-3%284-2%29%20%5D%2b1) brings us back to 17.

I attribute the third case to the explicit multiplication, meaning the division occurs before the 2 is distributed over the bracket.  But should the first two not yield the same result?

NOTE: The original problem was intentionally ambiguous, with the purpose of showing the dangers of the ÷ operator, so let's not talk about that.

Comment: If your question is just about the mathematics, then it is a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33215). If it is about how Wolfram Alpha decides to evaluate expressions, it is probably better for [mathematica.SE](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) (though I think they prefer questions about Mathematica proper, not Wolfram Alpha).

Comment: @Chris Are you actually asking a question, or just making an observation about Wolfie's behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with $÷ $ at all. It is all about how Alpha interprets "$2*[..]$" vs "$2[..]$".

The square bracket means a function application. Alpha gives precedence to $f[x]$ (expression $f$ applied to expression $x$, or $f(x)$) over other arithmetic operators. But since $2$ is not a function, $2[\cdots]$ is interpreted as $(2\times \cdots)$ *before the rest of the expression*.

You can easily see the difference is a simpler example:
$16 ÷ 2[3]$ is $$\frac{16}{2 \times 3}$$
but $16 ÷ 2*[3]$ is $$\frac{16}{2}\times 3.$$