# Order of computation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is 48÷2(9+3)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33215/what-is-48293)

In the field of real numbers, does the expression 10 / 2 * 5 make sense? Is it 25 or 1? Is it a bad question or the order of computation from left-to-right is implicit (axiomatic) when omitting parentheses?

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33215/what-is-48293) for discussion of the order of operations.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations

Comment: With the resources you have today, always do web search first then post here.

Answer (score 3):

The computer languages I have used explicitly say that 10/2*5=25.  For writing, I would always include the parentheses to be clear.

Answer (score 2):

The most widespread convention is that operations **of equal precedence** are performed from left to right in the absence of parentheses; by this convention $10/2\cdot 5=25$. However, it is violated often enough, intentionally or otherwise, that in such cases one should always supply enough parentheses or other cues to make the intended sense clear: $(10/2)\cdot 5$, $(10/2)(5)$, $\frac{10}2\cdot5$, $\frac12(10)(5)$, etc. However, this left-to-right convention is normally superseded by precedence conventions, so that $2+3\cdot5=17$, not $30$.

Most of the programming languages that I’ve seen follow these conventions, though they may differ slightly in the precedence of some operations; two exceptions that I know about are [Smalltalk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk), which uses a strict left-to-right convention with no built-in precedence hierarchy, and [APL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_%28programming_language%29), which, like the Iverson notation on which it was based, uses a strict right-to-left convention.