# Order of Operations: What is value of the $6/4*4\;$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, arithmetic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is 48÷2(9+3)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33215/what-is-48293)

My friend asked me value of expression `16/4*4.`
So what is value of `16/4*4`? Is it `16` or `1`.
if you solve it right to left it's 1. 
But if you solve it from left to right its value is 16.
So which one is correct. And why?

Comment: It depends on which of the two options you adopt, of course. Usually, it's done "left to right"; but this is just convention.

Comment: How is the above a regular expression?  (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularExpression.html)

Comment: You can also review [*Order of Operations*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations). Regards

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's an ambiguous expression, which is *best clarified* with the use of parentheses to make explicit the first operation to perform, and on which two integers.

That is, the expression is best expressed by presenting it as one of:

$\;(16 / 4)* 4 = 16\;\tag{1}$ OR $\;16/(4* 4)=1\,\;\tag{2}$

leaving *no room for confusion or ambiguity* on the part of the reader.

That said: 
Since division and multiplication are equal in precedence (see [***order of operations***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations)), and *absent any parentheses*, then by convention, we **evaluate from *left to right*.**

> **That is: we evaluate $\;16/4*4 = 4 * 4 = 16,\;$ just as we would evaluate $(1)$ above.**

---

I'll quote from Gerry Myerson's answer to [**this post**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33215/what-is-48293):

> "There is no Supreme Court for mathematical notation; there were no commandments handed down on Sinai concerning operational precedence; all there is, is convention, and different people are free to adhere to different conventions. Wise people will stick in enough parentheses to make it impossible for anyone to mistake the meaning."

They use $(1)$ when they mean $(1)$, and use $(2)$ when they mean $(2)$.

Answer (score 5):

Order of Operations demands that expressions are evaluated left to right.

Comment: Not always. $2^{2^3}$ is usually interpreted as $2^{(2^3)} = 256$, rather than $(2^2)^3=64$.

Comment: Right.  I should have mentioned that OO demands left to right after all other considerations.  Thank you for pointing that out.