# Precedence of $\times$ and $\cup$.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, notation

In topology, there is a very strong need of describing subsets of some product $X\times Y$ by means of unions and products.

For example, this is a very convenient way of describing subsets of the plane. (Which are common examples in, say, algebraic topology.)

> Is there any standard convention about the precedence of products and unions?

In particular, when I write $A\times B\cup C\times D$ would this be interpreted as $A\times(B\cup C)\times D$ or as $(A\times B)\cup(C\times D)$? I personally would go with the second option, because of the analogy with multiplication and addition, which for some reason seems to make sense to me. (And in that case there *is* a standard convention). Despite this analogy, I fear the omission of parentheses in the case of sets might be ambiguous to some people.

> Is it better to always use parentheses?

(Of course a downside of parentheses would be that the notation may become very cluttered, when the expressions are long.)

Comment: I would go with the first interpretation since $B \cup C$ is one object, not two disparate ones. This is, of course, unless I know/understand the context. When there's chance of confusion, use parentheses. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33215/what-is-48293 etc...

Comment: +1, nice question! Personal opinion: second, alike in multiplication and addition. I would also say that *especially* in long formulas like that I really do like parentheses, as without them it's much easier to get it in an incorrect way.

Comment: @Ilya: A very good point. My fear of notation becoming cluttered just might be unjustified.

Comment: Opinion: Third choice: always use parentheses.

Comment: I agree very strongly with @GEdgar: always use parentheses.

Comment: Ok, it seems the prevailing opinion is to always use parentheses. I've looked through some set theory and algebraic topology texts and that seems to be also the prevailing usage there. (Though I think none mention this explicitly.) I guess this settles the matter. Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 1):

If the context is product topology, I think it is more likely to mean the latter as A and C would often be open sets of some space X and B and D would be open sets of some space Y. And it doesn't make sense to take the union of B and C in that context.