# Can $7 + 4 \times 8$ have multiple answers?

Tags: arithmetic

My textbook says evaluate $7 + 4 \times 8$ in a revision course. Is it $7 + 4$, then multiply by 8 or $7 + (4 \times 8)$ ? The calculator automatically gives me the correct answer, so I am going to assume there is a universal rule for this.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33215/what-is-48293/33238#33238

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations

Comment: "The calculator automatically gives me the correct answer" A scientific calculator would give you an answer of 39, but try a simpler calculator (a four-function calculator, or a simple cellphone calculator) and see if you get the same answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By order of operations, the answer is $7+32 = 39$.  You do multiplication first, then addition.

Answer (score 1):

Remember BEDMAS; the order of operations.

> $\ \ \ \ \text{B - Brackets}$
>   $\ \ \ \ \text{E - Exponents}$
>   $\begin{cases} \text{D - Division (can be done with multiplication)} \\
> \text{M - Multiplication (can be done with division)} \\ \end{cases}$
>   $\begin{cases} \text{A - Addition (can be done with subtraction)} \\ \text{S - Subtraction (can be done with addition)} \\ \end{cases}$

There are no brackets, nor exponents. The first step would be to multiply. $4\times 8=32$. Then, the next step would be to add. $7+32=39$.
**Answer:**
$$\displaystyle \boxed{7+4\times 8=39}$$