# What is 6%2(2+1) and why?

Tags: functions

This one is a classic, but never-the-less, it's been bothering me since I've read several contradicting answers, yet none of them has convinced me completely. So, how do I properly and correclty calculate functions like this?

So: % refers to division,

6%2(2+1) or 6/2(2+1).

Comment: Where did you see those answers?  Does % mean "modulo"?  And how do you define the order of operations for these operations?

Comment: Terve! I'm afraid I don't expect this question to live long and prosper here. This is a smaller brother of the [near-memetic 48:2(9+3) thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/33215/11619) that no self-respecting mathematician will rule on. A quick summary. It is ambiguous. If you have been assigned the task of coding a parser for inline formulas, then you have to do it one way or the other. There is no unanimous correct interpretation. If your teacher gives you this, they should lose their license to teach.

Comment: The ÷ symbol needs to be taken out back and shot.

Comment: @Arkamis, most indeed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking your expression $6/2(2+1)$, it is clear to do the $2+1$ first because of the parentheses.  It is not clear whether the $(2+1)$ belongs in the denominator or the numerator.  All the programming languages I have seen would do this as $\frac 62 \cdot (2+1)=3\cdot 3=9$, but we get posts here that clearly intend that it be read as $\frac 6{2(2+1)}=1$.  It is not clear without additional parentheses. You should either complain to whoever sent you the expression, or try to determine from context what is meant.

Answer (score 0):

$$6 \,\% \,2 \cdot (2+1)= 6 \,\% \, 2 \cdot 3= 3 \cdot3=9$$
$\checkmark$ order of operations

Comment: But why you suggest this is the correct answer?

Comment: Follow order of operations: if you say that $\%$ denotes division, then we first compute the sum in the parentheses, then proceed to compute the division, then finally the multiplication. The order of the last two operations is because we read $6 \,\%\, 2 \cdot 3$ as $\frac{6}{2}\cdot3$, not $\frac{6}{2\cdot 3}$.

Comment: May you missed the point of [this highly upvoted answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/33238/11619)?

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: Conventionally, this is how this statement would be interpreted, in my opinion.