# If you see $A\div2B=C$, do you take $A\div 2B$ to be $(A\div 2)B$, or $A\div (2B)\,$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation, arithmetic

If you see
$$ A \div 2B = C$$
do you take $A \div 2B = (A\div 2)B$ or $= A\div (2B)$? How do I know which one to choose?

Comment: If division and multiplication take equal precedence, then the first.

Comment: If I see that I thwap the author for being imprecise.  Randall is right in the usual order of operations with $2B$ being short hand notation for $2\cdot B$.  However,  it may very well be meant to be understood as a single term $(2B)$.

Comment: @Salihcyilmaz: it does matter: if $A$ and $B$ are real numbers, $(A \div 2)B$ is only equal to $A \div (2B)$ if $A = 0$ or $B = 1$.

Comment: @RobArthan  I think he's referencing Alan's comment.  $2B$ is $2 \cdot B$ no matter what.

Comment: @Randall: perhaps you are right. I'll leave my comment anyway.

Comment: So we would say $A/B(C+D) = AC/B + AD/B $ ?

Comment: I would strongly advise against omitting the first pair of brackets in $(A/B)(C + D)$. Note that that left-to-right rule for multiplication when the multiplication sign is elided is dubious. If you see a multivariate polynomial like $3XYZ + 2XY$, it is usual to think of $3$ and $2$ as the coefficients of the monomials $XYZ$ and $XY$, i.e., to read it as $3(XYZ) + 2(XY)$. This doesn't make any difference when you plug in numbers, but it is the "right' reading in abstract algebra.

Comment: Some of my students do this and it's really annoying for the exact reason as the question alludes to.

Comment: I think [this previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2934967/ambiguity-with-parentheses-multiplications/2935025#2935025) of mine can give you some insight into why there is some confusion, though it doesn't give you a definitive answer.

Comment: At the risk of being flippant you *shouldn't* ever see $A\div 2B$.  No author should ever use it because it is is ambiguous and misleading.

Comment: " I think he's referencing Alan's comment. 2B is 2⋅B no matter what"  No.  It isn't.  We just gave an example where it is not.  If $2B$ is $2\cdot B$ no matter what then $A\div \color{green}{2B}$ is $A \div (2\cdot B)$.  This would be akin to claiming $2+B$ is $2+B$ always and then noticing that $-2+B$ *does* contain the *string* "$2+B$" within it. In this case the string does *not* mean $2+B$; It's just a string within a larger context.

Comment: To be flippant again *my* answer is.  By all rules it *ought* to mean $(A\div 2)B = \frac {A\times 2}B$ but I imagine over 98% of all mathematicians seeing it would read it as $A\div (2B) = \frac A{2B}$.  The convention of seeing a specific numeric value $2$ before a variable $B$ and interpreting it as the value $(2B)$ is just too common and too strong for us to *not* interpret it that way despite *ALL* the rules of order of operations tell us it is not so.

Comment: In mathematics you never write $A \div 2B$, so the question never comes up.  Agreeing with @fleablood  What you **might** see in a math paper is $A/2B$ meaning $\frac{A}{2B}$; since if you want $(A/2)B$ you would just write $AB/2$.

Comment: ALso, after the 5th grade you should never really see the the division sign, $\div$, ever again.  And $\frac A{2B}$ and $\frac A2B$ are utterly unambiguous.

Comment: When I can't tell I usually do it both ways so the grader is aware of the ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen $\log, \ln$, and $\lg$. Also $\log_{10}$ and $\log_e$. But I still hate it when people use $\log$ and they mean $\ln$. I've seen $\arctan, \operatorname{atan}$, and $\operatorname{atan2}$. Why can't we agree on which of $\Bbb N$ or $\Bbb W$ contains $0$? How many times do we have to explain that $\sqrt 9 = 3?$ What does PEMDAS say about $2^{3^4}$? Or $\cos 2 \cdot \dfrac{\pi}{3}$?

Yes, there are rules. Yet sometimes mathematician break them when it makes it easier for them to communicate. They always, in some way, explain what it means to them and why they are doing it that way. No that's not contradictory.  Done correctly, it's practical and efficient.

So where did you get $A\div2B$ from? Was it from a C programmer? How about an APL programmer? If you just made it up, what did you want it to mean? A question like that is just begging for context.

My opinion is that most mathematicians eschew unnecessary parenthesis. PEMDAS says that it means $(A \div B)C$. So, unless you meant $A\div (BC)$ don't bother.
Also, $``\div"$ is evil and should be avoided. It's main advantage was for the time when type was physically set into presses and $A\div B$ fit on one line while $\dfrac AB$ did not.

Note that $\dfrac A2B$ or $\dfrac{A}{2B}$ or $A \cdot \dfrac 12 \cdot B$ do not leave any confusion about what they mean.