# Simple BODMAS question including bracket expansion

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I am trying to understand what is seemingly basic arithmetic that is causing a divide amongst my colleagues

$$
8÷2(2+2)
$$

To me respecting the order of operations it would appear the answer is `16` while others say it is `1`. The latter value is coming from a colleague is quoting the distributive property having implicit brackets and thus should be `8÷2×(2+2)`.

Apologies if this is too simple of a question for this exchange.

Comment: 16  is correct. We can place /, *, +,- , () in any order, multiple interpretations can be possible. In order to avoid confusion we agree upon the BODMAS rule. the proper way to write this is $$\frac{8}{2}\times(2+2)$$As division is a binay operator then it can only take 8,2 are as its operands

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Update: looks like it's a been answered here as an "ambiguous notation" - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33215/what-is-48÷293

Comment: Thanks @HansLundmark, looks like it is answered there: _it is ambiguous and this notation should not be used_. Flagged it as dupe

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 16.
 $8\div2(2+2)=8\div2\times(2+2)=8\div2\times4$. When there are concatenated $\div$ and $\times$ the calculation should just be run from left to right. So, $8\div2\times4=4\times4=16$
Even though it's a handy mnemonic, I'm not a fan of BODMAS because, if you follow it to the letter, then $8-2+4=2$, which is incorrect. 
Your colleague is incorrect to say that there are implicit brackets. It might be that they are thinking of something like $8+2(2+2)$, where the expansion has to happen first, but only because $\times$ has to happen before $+$. This could be seen as implying brackets, something like $8+(2(2+2))$, but the extra brackets are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

$ 8 ÷ 2 (2 + 2) $

Considering the use of BODMAS, lets begin by evaluating the arithmetic operation in the Bracket (B), i.e.

$ 8 ÷ 2 (2 + 2) $ 
$ = 8 ÷ 2 × 4 $

After that, consider Division (D), i.e.

$ 8 ÷ 2 × 4 $ 
$ = 4 × 4 $

Finally, we end it via Multiplication (M), i.e.

$ 4 × 4 $ 
= $ 16 $ ...Ans.