# 10 + 67 × 2= ?, This question is causing a ruckus among my friend

Tags: arithmetic

Help!

How would you solve 10 + 67 × 2?

I solved by putting a bracket between 10 and 67. Then multiplying by 2
Like this (10 + 67)2 = 154

However, others insist it's 144 and I'm wrong.

Comment: You multiply first, then add. This ambiguity is exactly why we use brackets.

Comment: you do the multiplication first - so it's $67\times 5=335$, then $335+10=345$.

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) Wikipedia article

Comment: I think it's only natural one adds the bracket automatically considering the way the equation was written LRT

Comment: @mamuseferha you always follow order of operations. Even if it's written LTR with addition first, multiplication has higher precedence.

Comment: Okay @Andrew Li thank you

Comment: Does  $\ 10 + 67\, x\ $ or other polynomials also "cause ruckus"?  If not, why?

Comment: Before needing to ask another arithmetic question, as it relates to division and parentheses, I suggest also reading [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33215/what-is-48%c3%b7293?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 6):

You can't write $(10+67)\cdot 2$ (because you add a $10$ that doesn't exist), but if you want to use brackets, you can say: $(67+10)\cdot 2-10=67+67+10+10-10=144$. Or $10=5\cdot 2$: $2\cdot (67+5)=144$.

Answer (score 2):

If they meant $(10 + 67) \times 2$, they should have written that. Otherwise one should assume the standard order of operations is meant. Go to Wolfram Alpha and put in `10 + 67 * 2`. It will answer 144 because there is nothing to indicate the addition should be done first.

Another possibility is that your friend is trying to create the next viral math formula. I suggest your friend should go back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 1):

First multiply, than add:

$$10+67\cdot5=10+335=345$$