# Evaluate :-$150 ÷ [66 ÷ 11(26-23)]$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

> Evaluate :-$150 ÷ [66 ÷ 11(26-23)]$.

This question is present in my brother's mathematics book. I followed BODMAS rule and got the answer but the book has a different answer and not following the proper order. I have shown my steps below. Please verify if I am wrong or the book's answer is. Thank you!

$150÷[66÷11(26-23)]$

$\rightarrow  150÷[66÷11(3)]$

$\rightarrow  150÷[6×3]$

$\rightarrow  150÷18$ $=  \frac{15}{18} =  \frac{25}{3}$ .

However the answer shown in the book is **$75$**.

Comment: Please Reformat the Question . It is difficult to read them like that .

Comment: I am new here, can you do it for me?

Answer (score 1):

For $[66\div11\{3\}]$ multiplication comes before division.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33215/what-is-48%c3%b7293

Comment: @LearningMathematics Feel free to mark it as duplicate.

Comment: Can you please explain why multiplication comes before division here? Because if we follow the order we need to go from left to right and divison comes first here.

Comment: There is a detailed discussion in the link above.

Comment: There is no proper explanation to suggest your answer is correct!

Answer (score 0):

If the book says the answer is $75$ then it is referring to $150\div [ 66\div \{11(26-23)\}]$. You can see that formatting the operation as I did previously is not as "problematic" as formatting it like this: $150 ÷ [66 ÷ 11(26-23)]$